# Change image with jquery when an accordian header changes

Tags: jquery

I have an accordion setup for faqs, with a changing background image. I am now trying to add an arrow up or down to the .ac-header depending on the active state of the .ac-header. Here is my current code:

```
<ul id="faqs-list" class="fd-accordion">
    <li>
        <header class="ac-header">
            <h4>1. Question 1?</h4>
            <img src="assets/images/arrow-down.png" class="arrow" alt="arrow" />
        </header>
        <div class="ac-content">
            <p>Answer 1</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <header class="ac-header">
            <h4>1. Question 2?</h4>
            <img src="assets/images/arrow-down.png" class="arrow" alt="arrow" />
        </header>
        <div class="ac-content">
            <p>Answer 2</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>



$(function(){
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ac-content").hide();

  $('.ac-header').on("click", function (e) {
  $('.ac-header').not(this)
               .removeClass("active")
               .next(".ac-content")
               .hide();

  $(this).toggleClass("active")
       .next(".ac-content")
       .toggle($(this).is(".active"));
  });
});
```

Looking for suggestions on what should be added to the javascript to change the image "arrow-down.png". Thanks!

Comment: the norm would be to do it using CSS and not inserting `img` tag. The class change would be sufficient to switch background

Comment: `$(function(){` remove this

Comment: check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/no68kyje/). working perfectly. change image using `.attr()`

Comment: The issue is there is already a background image within the .ac-header. that is why I added the img tag. The original code i was working from had <span class="arrow"></span> instead of img and then css, but I would still need java script to change the the arrow. I can edit my original post to include the html/css for this if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : after toggling class active, check if header has active class or not and change image accordingly

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".ac-content").hide();

      $('.ac-header').on("click", function (e) {
      $('.ac-header').not(this)
                   .removeClass("active")
                   .next(".ac-content")
                   .hide();

      $('.ac-header').find('img').attr('src','assets/images/arrow-down.png').attr('alt','down-arrow'); 

     $(this).toggleClass("active")
       .next(".ac-content")
       .toggle($(this).is(".active"));

     if($(this).hasClass('active'))
     {
      $(this).find('img').attr('src','assets/images/arrow-right.png').attr('alt','right-arrow'); 
     }

    });
 });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/59jrxpab/18/)**

Comment: This changed the arrow, but not until the answer was hidden again.

Comment: so which link is useful to you? i will update in answer accordingly

Comment: jsfiddle.net/59jrxpab/18